# Passing a variable result from one view controller to another non-view controller swift file

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make an iOS app that takes a username from a text field, turns it into a string and passes it to another file I have called HomeModel.swift. This file is **NOT** a ViewController but I need that variable name to add to a URL.

Currently, my app is set up with an initial view controller that has a text field for a username and a Login button. When I click the login button it takes the textfield entry and turns it into a string which I then use to turn into a label on the next ViewController. My issue is taking the username variable (that I used to turn into a label) and passing it to a non-ViewController swift file so I can do some "behind-the-scenes" stuff with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have spent hours trying to find an answer but came up short handed.

This is my initial ViewController

```
import UIKit

class Home: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var TextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var PasswordField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var LoginBtn: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.TextField.delegate = self
    self.PasswordField.delegate = self

    func checkField(sender: Any?) {
        if (TextField.text?.isEmpty)! || (PasswordField.text?.isEmpty)!
        {
            LoginBtn.isEnabled = false

        }
        else
        {
            LoginBtn.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
}

//Hide keyboard when touched outisde keyboard
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    PasswordField.resignFirstResponder()
    return (true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let DestViewController : ViewTwo = segue.destination as! ViewTwo

    DestViewController.PasswordText = PasswordField.text!
    DestViewController.LabelText = TextField.text!
}

}
```

This is the HomeModel.swift file

```
import Foundation

protocol HomeModelProtocol: class {
func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}

class HomeModel: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {

//properties

weak var delegate: HomeModelProtocol!

func viewDidLoad() {

}

func downloadItems() {

    let myusername = //Variable from initial controller here

    let urlPath = "http://urlhere.com/index.php?username="+myusername //this is where the list of users are

    let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
    let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to download data")
        }
        else {
            print("Contact List Data Downloaded")
            self.parseJSON(data!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {
    var jsonResult = NSArray()
    print (jsonResult)

    do {
        jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
    let locations = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
    {
        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

        let location = LocationModel()

        //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
        if let name = jsonElement["name"] as? String,
            let phone = jsonElement["phone"] as? String
        {
            location.name = name
            location.phone = phone
        }

        locations.add(location)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

        self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: locations)

    })
}
}
```

Comment: If it's just a normal class, just use `yourClassObject.label.text = "\(userName)"`. Other case try delegates or `NSNotificationCenter`

Comment: Provide the code for both HomeModel.swift and your login method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally from what you are describing this is simply passing your object between view controllers you are having. Assume having:

```
class LoginData {
   var username: String?
}
```

Now your first view controller seems to be your entry point so it is the one that creates it for instance on "next" button pressed. Then this object should be passed to the new view controller:

```
@IBAction onNextPressed() {
    let loginData = LoginData() // Create object
    loginData.username = self.textField.text // Set data to it

    let nextController = UIStoryboard(...) as! NextViewController // Generate new view controller
    nextController.loginData = loginData // Assign login data
    navigationController.push(... nextController ...) // Show controller
}
```

So then the next view controller should use this object:

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {
    var loginData: LoginData?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.label.text = loginData?.username
    }

...
```

In some cases though (which seems like yours) it might make sense to preserve data globally. To do so all you need is a static variable. In your case I suggest you create a new object `User`.

```
class User {
    static var current: User?

    var loginData: LoginData?
}
```

Now here `User` only contains login data but there is also a placeholder to add an instance of a current user which may be used whenever inside the app.

Now for this case the first view controller does not need to pass the data to next view controller but rather set the current user:

```
@IBAction onNextPressed() {
    let loginData = LoginData() // Create object
    loginData.username = self.textField.text // Set data to it

    let newUser = User() // Create a new user
    newUser.loginData = loginData // Assign login data to it
    User.current = newUser // Set current user

    let nextController = UIStoryboard(...) // Generate new view controller
    navigationController.push(... nextController ...) // Show controller
}
```

And the new view controller does not need a reference to login data:

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.label.text = User.current?.loginData?.username
    }

...
```

This is great when you need to use these data all over the app so as you mentioned some url you can now call anywhere `User.current?.serviceURL` if you implement:

```
extension User {
   var serviceURL: URL? {
      guard let username = username else {
         return nil
      }
      return URL(string: "https://some.pat/\(username)/resource_name")
   }
}
```

I hope this clears a few things about passing data in Swift.